# Useing Oracle 10g database for ASP.NET session management

Tags: asp.net, oracle, session-management

I am developing a web application. 
For some reasons, I need to use external storage for storing session state. 
As I am using Oracle 10g as backend database, can I use same oracle 10g db for storing session state also?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the built in session API, you should implement your own [Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). Should not be too hard, since you can change the storage model only, and do not have to worry about acquiring and releasing session state for requests, this is done by the built-in Session state provider.

Edit: It seems that Oracle themselves provides an implementation of Session state, that you could use. http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/dotnet/aspnet/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what Oracle do themselves with their [Application Express](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html) web application tool.  Essentially you just give each session a unique session ID and then record all session state in a table like this one:

```
create table session_state
( session_id integer
, item_name varchar2(100)
, item_value varchar2(4000)
, primary key (session_id, item_value)
);
```